# Is normalized RBF always better than RBF

Tags: matrices, machine-learning, pseudoinverse, artificial-intelligence, radial-basis-functions

The question is as the title. Mathematically, I want to know does the following inequation always hold for any vector $\mathbf b$?

$\mathbf b^T \mathbf B \mathbf B^+ \mathbf b \, \ge  \, \mathbf b^T \mathbf H \mathbf H^+ \mathbf b$

Where $\mathbf H$ is a N x M sized matrix (M < N), its element $h_{i j} = exp(-\frac{\|\mathbf x_i - \mathbf c_j\|^2}{2 \sigma^2})$, $x_i, c_j \in R^n$.  Matrix $\mathbf B$ is row normalized matrix of $\mathbf H$, i.e. $b_{i j} = \frac{h_{i j}}{\sum_j h_{i j}}$. $\mathbf B^+, \mathbf H^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) for $\mathbf B, \mathbf H$ respectively, and size of vector $\mathbf b$ is $N$.

This question arises in the study of [normalized RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network#Normalized_architecture), where $\mathbf H$ denotes the output matrix for standard RBF, and $\mathbf B$ denotes the output matrix for normalized RBF (NRBF). The wiki page gives a justification that the NRBF makes sense. However, there is no proof neither in the wiki page nor the original paper that NRBF is always better than RBF. The original paper is: ["Normalized Gaussian Radial Basis Function Networks"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.108.9852&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Denote the observed output on training samples as $\mathbf b$, the best estimation made by RBF and NRBF is $\mathbf H \mathbf H^+ \mathbf b$ and $\mathbf B \mathbf B^+ \mathbf b$. Thus we want the squared error $(\mathbf H \mathbf H^+ \mathbf b)^T \mathbf H \mathbf H^+ \mathbf b$ and $(\mathbf B \mathbf B^+ \mathbf b)^T \mathbf B \mathbf B^+ \mathbf b$ be as close to zero as possible, which can be deduced to the question listed at the top.

I now know the inequation does not always hold as some counter examples are found. But it's better to have an analytic proof. And it's desired to know when RBF is better than normalized RBF and visa versa.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why is it that you want  $\mathbf B \mathbf B^+$ or $\mathbf H \mathbf H^+$ to be as close to the identity as possible. Intuitively, that seems bad to me, because if you want your network to learn the identity function, then it seems to just provide a memorization of the training data. It is not clear that would provide good generalization (i.e. being close to expected error). Or maybe you'd like to clarify what you mean by "best"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The training is using least square condition. That is to minimize the sum of squared error. Here the observation is $\mathbf b$ and the estimation is $\mathbf H \mathbf H^+ \mathbf b$. Thus it is natural to minimize $\mathbf H \mathbf H^+ \mathbf b - \mathbf b$, which is $(\mathbf H \mathbf H^+ - \mathbf I) \mathbf b$. That's why we want $\mathbf H \mathbf H^+$ (and $\mathbf B \mathbf B^+$) to be close to identity matrix. I think that is what Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse for.

Comment: @CharlieParker: the learning we talked here is the weights from hidden layer to the output layer. when the weights from input layer to the hidden layer ( in RBF case, the centers) are fixed. It is indeed to learn a identity matrix. The generalization is done by the non-linear transfer function in the hidden layer.

Comment: @CharlieParker: You are right. I made a mistake and I modified the question to correct it. Can you have a look again?